# ios XML parsing : Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=76 on some devices

Tags: iphone, ios, nsxmlparser, nsxmlparsererrordomain

I get this error in my app on one specific iPhone 4 device while parsing an XML Feed:

```
error parsing XML: Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=76
```

I am not able to determine why it's happening on this particular device and not others: this is the same feed. There are no XML errors in the feed XML structure and all devices have the same global general settings.

According to the docs, Error 76 is `NSXMLParserTagNameMismatchError`.

Answer (score 2):

Your xml may be inconsistent. Validate it against http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: no, the problem only oocurs on one device. after some tests, it seems related to the 3G connection quality. the problem does not occurs on the same device with Wifi.

Comment: So you may be getting partial document.

Answer (score 2):

Cut and paste your xml [here](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_validate.asp) to validate. The error messages are pretty solid.

Comment: Link is dead @Eric

Answer (score 2):

this error happens when the closing tag doesn't match the opening tag, like so:

```
<hello>
    <hi />
    <hi />
    <hi />
</goodbye>
```

or

```
<hello />
    <hi />
    <hi />
    <hi />
</hello>
```

(the tag was closed on the first line)